# Deleting a Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to delete an GAE application after it has been created?

I made a mistake while typing the name and now have a dummy application that I haven't been able to remove.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

With the new Google Cloud console, you can still disable GAE applications as before (App Engine --> Settings --> Disable).  They cannot currently be deleted.

If you are sure that you aren't using the project for anything else, you can delete the entire project by going to IAM --> Settings --> Shut Down. This button is in the header and a bit tricky to spot. It looks like this:

[image]

---

As of [AppEngine SDK 1.2.6](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/10/app-engine-sdk-126-released-with.html) it's possible to [delete apps completely](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/adminconsole.html#delete_app). But beware, the app-id won't be usable again.

Comment: You can send them an email if you REALLY want the ID.  They can give it back for a specific project.  I haven't personally done it but I saw people in google groups saying it's possible

Comment: @Patrice What is their email address?

Comment: @suzanshakya I believe support would help with that, so it's not really an email, more the ticketing system offered to those with a support package. If you don't have one... not sure to be honest.

Comment: These instructions leed to the whole project shutdown. If your project hosts other things than GAE that you want to keep you shouldn't follow this solution.

Answer (score 77):

As most of the answers are outdated or contradictive and this is an important question I decided to clarify current possible solutions when intending to delete an application in Google App Engine or having related issues.

Currently, there is **no way to delete** an existing app in GAE. Once created it cannot be removed, nor its initial settings can be changed (like the region where it was deployed). The only possible workaround is starting a new project and deploying a new application. There were feature requests in Google Issue Tracker regarding these issues: [deleting an app](https://issuetracker.google.com/35874988) and [changing zone/region](https://issuetracker.google.com/36878762). You can still delete the whole project as described in Steve Armstrong's answer, but bear in mind that this will remove everything you created there (like GCE, GKE etc.), not only GAE.

However, it all depends on why you would like to delete your app. If you would simply like to stop it from serving requests or you don't want it to incur further costs, you can disable the app as described in the GCP docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/?csw=1#disabling_an_application).

Comment: This should be the valid answer

Comment: Why do i currently see a Delete button at the top then ? I was able to delete an app, but i am not sure it deleted the relevant files in Storage

Comment: the delete button is there to delete specific versions of your application

Answer (score 25):

This feature is already logged, please star it:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=335

Comment: wow. what !! I can't delete the project because I have GKE in there as well. I was trying to move something to AppEngine. I will never consider using a platform that is missing such a basic feature.

Answer (score 11):

To disable /delete your application:

- In the Administration Console, click your application to make it the active application.
- Click Application Settings on the left side under Administration.
- Click Disable Application.
- Click Disable Application Now.
- If you want to delete your app:

  1. If billing is enabled for your app, disable billing. You aren't allowed to delete before you do this.
  2. Click Request Permanent Deletion. The application will be deleted in approximately 72 hours.
     To re-enable your disabled application, click Re-Enable Application.

[image]
[source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings#disable_or_delete_your_application)

Answer (score 9):

There currently isn't a way to delete a GAE application.

Answer (score 9):

I was evaluating if we could use AppEngine and ran the standard tutorial which created a test app for me under my the default project. When I tried to delete the App I was shocked that it can't be done ! The only way is to delete the project which would delete all other GKE and any other services under that account.

After a bunch of research and calling product support of Google this what they suggested: To upgrade to Silver Support for 150$/month and send them an email to delete the app.

Here is the chat session with Google Support. If you were considering using Google AppEngine I would think again.

[image]

Comment: As of 2024, there is no tier of support that will allow you to delete or change existing App Engine or Firebase Project locations (as recently indicated by GCP support). It's a major product flaw that has no timeline for resolution. The best explanation I've found online to date is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35874988#comment250

Answer (score 9):

Beyond disabling the App Engine application you can:

- Disable it's API permission under `APIs & Services`
- Remove the App Engine related files from `Storage`
- Delete App Engine permissions under `IAM & Admin`
- Delete the App Engine `Service account`

This will freeze all App Engine related billing charges for the undeletable disabled App engine application. At least it worked for me :)

Comment: As the App engine is disabled it will stop incurring on most charges, but the 3 buckets created by the app engine might still incur storage charges as some of them save the container images for every version. They're easy to identify as the bucket names are suffixed by the app engine URI.

Answer (score 7):

This issue has been fixed; see the docs here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/?csw=1#delete_app

Comment: That no longer exists. you can't delete a GAE app, only disable. You have to delete the entire project which is stupid. thanks google.

Answer (score 3):

Carlos, you're right that the issue has been fixed, and I up-voted you for that. However, your link is a little outdated and an updated link is listed below.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings#Disable_or_Delete_Your_Application

Comment: That no longer exists. you can't delete a GAE app, only disable. You have to delete the entire project which is stupid. thanks google

Answer (score 3):

open https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?organizationId=0 ,select the project(or application) to be deleted,then click `delete`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to delete some legacy Google App Engine applications I made years ago, but when I tried to delete them from the new Google Cloud Platform (like this: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787#shut-down-a-project)  I kept getting "You do not have permission" errors. The solution I found was to sign up for a free trial of Google Cloud Platform, then I was able to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find to delete the default app-engine, however if you navigate to App Engine > Settings , there is a button to Disable it and it stop serving. when you click on the button type the project name in the prompt.

[image]

[image]